# VBA , Why this if condition doesn't work?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

This is my condition

```
If Range("calcu") = "Orifice diameter" Or Range("calcu") = "Perforated area" And Range("oridia").Value < Range("gasinp").Value Then
```

if i remove Or Range("calcu") = "Perforated area" then it works but together with OR & AND , it does not work.

Why ?

Comment: does `Range("calcu")` represent one cell?

Comment: yes. is there is any easy way to write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parenthesis, the last frontier.

I think you were looking for this:

```
If (Range("calcu") = "Orifice diameter" Or Range("calcu") = "Perforated area") _
   And Range("oridia").Value < Range("gasinp").Value Then
```

Comment: +1 Sidenote for @user2703472: parenthesis indicate precedence whereas the inner parenthesis always have priority. This is something you should def take into account for the future. Consider accepting the reply if it helped you out.

Comment: vba was reading your condition like `Range("calcu")` or otherwise `Range("calcu") = "Perforated area" And Range("oridia").Value < Range("gasinp").Value`. AND is applied before OR, like * and / are applied before + and - in mathematics. I thought you just forgot them or you didn't know how to use in that formula